# Is it possible to check if word stored on stack is palyndrome without ANY additonal data structures in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, stack, palindrome

In C++ programme, let's analyse stack data structure. 
My question is : Is it possible to check if the given stack contains palindrome or not WITHOUT ANY additional data structure and without modifying the stack? You are allowed to decompose the stack so long as you put it back together again (I mean that by modifying).

Example 1:  s = {1, 2, 3, 2, 1}  - it's palindrome 
Example 2:  s = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}  - it's not a palindrome

- My only idea is to do it with recursion:

---

```
void checkStack(Stack<int>& s){
    //Exit condition
    if(s.numberOfElements() == 0){
        return;
    } 

    int temp = s.pop(); 

    checkStack(s);

    s.push(temp); 
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198269/discussion-on-question-by-kenan-saracevic-is-it-possible-to-check-if-word-stored).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to check if word stored on stack is palyndrome without
>   ANY additonal data structures in C++

I think that you mean by data structures some other abstract data structures or containers like list, vector and so on.

You can do your task by enclosing in a wrapper the standard class `std::stack<int>`.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stack>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

bool is_palindrome( const std::stack<int> &st )
{
    struct wrapper : std::stack<int>
    {
        wrapper( const std::stack<int> &st ) : std::stack<int>( st ) {}

        bool is_palindrome() const
        {
            return std::equal( std::begin( c ), std::next( std::begin( c ), c.size() / 2 ),
                               std::rbegin( c ) );
        }
    } w( st );


    return w.is_palindrome();
}

int main() 
{
    std::stack<int> st1( std::stack<int>::container_type{ 1, 2, 3, 2, 1  } );

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_palindrome( st1 ) << '\n';

    std::stack<int> st2( std::stack<int>::container_type{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5  } );

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_palindrome( st2 ) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
true
false
```

The class `wrapper` has an access to the protected data member `c` of the class `std::stack<int>` that denotes the underlying container.

Comment: quite some cheating, though I wouldnt know how to solve it without ;)

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I am pretty sure that you do not quote the task description fully correct. Several things are fishy about the task...

For one, one could do some hairsplitting and argue that it is impossible to use a `std::stack` without using any other data structure. A `std::stack` is just a container adapter that is build upon some underlying container. The default is a `std::deque`. Strictly speaking, using a `std::stack` without using any other data structure makes no sense.

Next, you are not allowed to modify the stack, but you are allowed to decompose it, as long as you put it back together again. This basically allows you to do anything. What I mean is, that you can for example write a function that returns you the nth element, eg:

```
int access(std::stack<int> s, size_t i) {
    while (i--) s.pop();
    return s.top();
}
```

Using this it is kind of trivial to write a test for palindrome. However this is basically treating the stack as if it wasn't a stack. For a similar approach that bypasses the stackyness of the `std::stack` see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57597611/4117728).

Note that for the little cheat above I had to make a copy of the stack (`s` is passed by value) and I cannot imagine a solution, even a recursive one, that would not use at least a second stack. When you decompose the stack you need to store the elements somewhere, otherwise how would you restore it afterwards?

Let's forget about the exact task for a moment and consider how can we check if a `std::stack` contains a palindrome (without the unclear constraints), then one simple solution would be

```
bool check_palindrome(std::stack<int>& s) {
    std::stack<int> t;
    while (t.size() < s.size()) {
        auto temp = s.top();
        s.pop();
        t.push(temp);
    }
    if (t.size() > s.size()) t.pop();
    return s==t;
}
```

This could also be turned into a recursive method (to be honest I dont really get the hype about recursion), but I wouldn't know how to do it without the second stack. Also I didn't bother to reconstruct the original stack, but it would be easy to do so.